# Automating Org Export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I find myself pressing `C-c C-e l o yes RET` quite often in org-mode because I want to view the file I'm working on as a PDF.

My simplistic attempts of automating this by feeding "lo" to `org-export-dispatch` were foiled by this interactive function not accepting any arguments as a quick look at its source code revealed.

How can this be automated so I can assign a shorter key binding to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try binding `(org-open-file (org-latex-export-to-pdf))` to a key combination of your choice?

Comment: Thanks! Do you also have an idea how to get rid of having to type "yes" hit return to reload the PDF?

Comment: No, sorry; I also would like to know the answer to that. I have global-auto-revert-mode set to t but that makes no difference.